# How to write a unit test for "T must be a reference type"?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Consider:

```
class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
}
```

In that case, the where clause is enforcing a specification that MyClass is only a generic of a reference type.

Ideally I should have a unit test that tests this specification.  However, this unit test obviously won't work, but it explains what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
[Test]
[DoesNotCompile()]
public void T_must_be_a_reference_type()
{
    var test = new MyClass<int>();
}
```

What can I do to test a spec that's implemented by not allowing the code to compile?

**EDIT**:

More info:  Ok, so my reasoning for doing this (haha) is that I've been following a TDD methodology, in which you can't write any code unless you have a failing unit test.  Let's say you had this:

```
class MyClass<T> { }
```

What test can you write that would fail unless T were a class?  Something like `default(T) == null`?

**Further EDIT**:

So after a "root cause analysis" on this, the problem is that I was relying on `default(T)` being `null` in a consumer of this class, in an implicit way.  I was able to refactor that consumer code into another class, and specify a generic type restriction there (restricting it to `class`) which effectively makes that code not compile if someone were to remove the restriction on the class I'm talking about above.

Comment: Why aren't you unit testing that the class is named `MyClass`?

Comment: @SLaks: technically var test = new MyClass<int>(); would test that, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think @SLaks was using sarcasm to prove the point that you don't need to test the compiler... that's Microsoft's job.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: my point is that if you're following TDD, you wouldn't have created the class unless you'd written your first unit test, which wouldn't have compiled unless you were using the name of a class that didn't exist.  So yes, your first unit test implicitly tests the name of the class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why would you need a unit test for this? Do you write a unit test for a method such as

```
public void Foo(string x)
```

to check that it can only take strings, and not integers? If not, what do you see as the difference?

EDIT: Just to be slightly less whimsical: in this case the spec is validated by the *declaration*. Tests should generally test *behaviour*. That's one of the things I like about Code Contracts: I don't feel any need to unit test the contracts unless they express something complicated - in which case it's that complexity that I'd be testing, not the "contracts are enforced" bit.

EDIT: To respond to the question edit:

> What test can you write that would fail unless T were a class?

You *could* write something like:

```
Type definition = typeof(MyClass<>);
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => definition.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)));
```

However, that seems to be going against the real purpose of testing...

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make my unit tests include all specs for the unit under test.

Comment: @Jon Funny, we thought about exactly the same example

Comment: @Scott Whitlock - But simply that the code compiles **is** your test.

Comment: @Scott: I don't think TDD should require this. Again, you wouldn't write a test to make sure that you can't pass invalid arguments. Your tests drive the *positive* side of the design ("I can use a reference type argument") but not necessarily the *negative* side. Ultimately all testing should be pragmatic - but testing the compiler *isn't* a pragmatic use of your time, IMO.

Comment: Ok, you explained why I didn't need the test, and gave me a working answer anyway, +2 for you!  :

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't test whether the compiler does its work. If you specify this in code, this is enough. From a code perspective, this is roughly the same as this:

```
[Test]
public void Test_whether_add_works()
{
    int i = 1 + 2;

    Assert.AreEqual(3, i);
}
```

Comment: '[Test] public void Running1984() { Assert.AreEqual(5, 2 + 2); }'

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question! So much agree with your test driven approach. What you are struggling with is actually the clash of two paradigms. The old paradigm that programs should be proven correct using mathematics without running them (a legacy of our profession’s ancestry in mathematics) and the new paradigm that programd should be proven correct by executing with example use cases, ie tests. So what you are about to try is to apply the practice of the new paradigm on an artifact of the old paradigm, which of course won’t really work…

More on the dichotomy of types and tests, see this excellent article by Chris Smith, http://web.archive.org/web/20080822101209/http://www.pphsg.org/cdsmith/types.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing a correct unit test? It looks like your a going to test C# compiler but not your code.